# Integrations tests with ASPNetCore and ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

I have an ASP.Net Core 1.1 project that is using ServiceStack Core. I am trying to write a basic integration test that looks like so:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BasicStartupTest
{
    TestServer Server;
    HttpClient Client;
    const string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:57893";
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        Server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void OneTimeTearDown()
    {
        Server.Dispose();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldHitHealthEndpointAndReturn200()
    {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync("/health");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Problem is, when it tried to run the GetAsync function from the Client instance, i get the following stack trace:

```
Result StackTrace:  at ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest.get_UserHostAddress() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a61371dd01fad6bd\src\ServiceStack\Host\NetCore\NetCoreRequest.cs:line 215
   at ServiceStack.HttpRequestExtensions.GetAttributes(IRequest request) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a61371dd01fad6bd\src\ServiceStack\HttpRequestExtensions.cs:line 844
   at ServiceStack.AppHostBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context, Func`1 next) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a61371dd01fad6bd\src\ServiceStack\AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 113
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

It goes on, but it looks like there is an issue with some get_UserHostAddress function in ServiceStack when I try to make a call to the endpoint in my integration test.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [proper Integration Test](http://docs.servicestack.net/testing#integration-testing) with a real self host HTTP Server enabled, for .NET Core the AppSelfHostBase class is available in the ServiceStack.Kestrel NuGet package.